# Trac Login with --basic-auth

Tags: trac

I need to use Trac for project management, but I am having problems with authentication. I don't have Apache, I'm using nginx and the tracd server.

To create the user, I used the command:

```
htpasswd -c /home/ubuntu/trac/projeto/.htpasswd usuario
```

To upload the service I'm using the following command:

```
/home/ubuntu/trac/virtualvenv/bin/tracd -p 3050 --basic-auth="/home/ubuntu/trac/projeto,/home/ubuntu/trac/projeto/.htpasswd," /home/ubuntu/trac/projeto
```

When I call the project in the browser, the login window is presented to me, which always fails, even informing the user and the correct password.

[image: Login]

[image: Error]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try: `--basic-auth="projeto,/home/ubuntu/trac/projeto/.htpasswd,trac"`. See [TracStandalone](https://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracStandalone) for details.

Comment: It worked with in the following way:
tracd -s --port 3050 --basic-auth="care,/home/ubuntu/trac/projeto/.htpasswd,trac" projeto
Thanks RjOllos!